# Why does my CD drive pop open randomly?

Tags: debian, data-cd

I have Debian 9 and at random times my CD drive pops open. Sometimes it pops open while browsing on Firefox, and sometimes it pops open while I'm just moseying around my desktop. A few times it even popped open during boot.

How can I figure out what's happening?

Comment: if it randomly pops open in the bios, I guess your drive is faulty. as a workaround maybe you could soft lock the tray, if the drive still respects that.

Comment: Thank you, but no. My CD drive pops open randomly in Linux only. In Windows, it doesn't pop open randomly.